# VPN from Windows XP to OpenSwan: correct setup?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, vpn, ipsec, openswan

Main question is what I am doing wrong in my OpenSwan or L2TP client setup?

I am trying to create a Linux OpenSwan VPN connection from Windows XP machine, using preshared key and the builtin Windows XP L2TP IPsec option.

I have followed the instructions in [Linux Home networking Wiki](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch35_:_Configuring_Linux_VPNs#Scenario) for setting up OpenSwan and a guide to making it [work with the Windows XP client](http://www.jacco2.dds.nl/networking/win2000xp-openswan.html), but am now stuck.

The net setup is as follows:

```
[my windows client, private IP A]<->[f/wall B]<-internet->[g/w X]<->[Linux OpenSwan server Y]
A - private subnet /24
B - internet address
X - internet address /24
Y - internet address on same subnet as X
```

What I essentially want is for computer with A address to feel and work, as if it was in X subnet for purposes of outgoing and incoming TCP and UDP connections.

My OpenSwan setup is as follows:

/etc/ipsec.conf (AAA and YYY indicates ip address parts of A and Y addresses):

```
conn net-to-net
        authby=secret
        left=B
        leftsubnet=AAA.AAA.AAA.0/24
        leftnexthop=%defaultroute
        right=Y
        rightsubnet=YYY.YYY.YYY.0/24
        rightnexthop=B
        auto=start
```

the secret in /etc/ipsec.secrets is listed as:

```
B Y : PSK "0xMysecretkey"
```

where B & Y stand for respective IP adresses of gateway B and linux server Y

My L2TP WinXP setup is:

- IP of destination: Y
- don't prompt for username
- security options: typical, require secured pass, don't require  data encryption, IPSec PSK set to 0xMysecretkey
- networking options: VPN Type: L2TP IPSec VPN; TCPIP protocol (with automatic IP address assignment) and QOS packet schedulers enabled

The error I get from Windows client is 789: "error during initial negotiation"

Answer (score 1):

without `(left,right)protoport=17/1701` you've configured the openswan side for tunnel mode ipsec, not transport mode to encrypt l2tp.

what does main mode debugging say on the linux end? i bet it's a protocol mismatch.

you can also turn on RAS debugging on the winXP side

Comment: thank you, i got a bit ill and haven't been able to pursue this further, but i'll get back to it, when i am on track.